# Hovering effect flickers using css

Tags: html, css, hover

I tried to do simple hovering effect on background of an element, but when the cursor is on the element, before finishing the whole transition on background, the background flickers for some moments then the flickering is stoped.

```css
div.nav {float:left;}
div.nav ul{list-style-type: none;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           width: 180px;}
div.nav ul li{border:1px solid #EAEAEA;}
div.nav ul li a {display:inline-block;
                 color: black;
                 width:180px;
                 margin:0 auto;
                 padding:50px 0;
                 text-decoration: none;
                 text-align:center;
                 text-transform:uppercase;
                 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 gold;
           -webkit-transition: linear 1s;
                 -moz-transition: linear 1s;
                 transition: linear 1s;
           cursor:pointer;}
div.nav ul li a:hover{  box-shadow: inset 400px 0 0 0 gold;}
div.nav ul li a i{display:block;
                 margin-bottom:5px;}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
       <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>About Me</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Resume</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

I tried to find the reason of the flickering but changing paddings and width but couldn't find any.

Comment: curiosity: why are you using `box-shadow` instead `background-color` in order to achieve your effect?

Comment: i wanted the transition like, after hovering background color will be changed from left to right. I found with this idea with box shadow because I don't know how to change background color on hovering with transition from one side to another side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be helpful: [Sliding Background Effect](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/sliding_background_effect_on_link_hover.htm)

However, I hope this could help:

```css
div.nav {
  float: left;
}

div.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 180px;
}

div.nav ul li {
  border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}

div.nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, gold, gold 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
  background-position: 100% 0;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

div.nav ul li a:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

div.nav ul li a i {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    div.nav {float:left;}
    div.nav ul{list-style-type: none;
               margin: 0;
               padding: 0;
               width: 180px;}
    div.nav ul li{border:1px solid #EAEAEA;}
    div.nav ul li a {display:inline-block;
                     position:relative;
                     z-index:2;
                     color: black;
                     width:180px;
                     margin:0 auto;
                     padding:50px 0;
                     text-decoration: none;
                     text-align:center;
                     text-transform:uppercase;
               -webkit-transition: ease 1s;
                     -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
                     transition: all ease 1s;
               cursor:pointer;}

    div.nav ul li a:after{ 
                     content:"";
                     z-index:-1;
                     width: 0%;
                     height: 100%;
                    background-color: gold;
                     position: absolute;
                     top:0;
                     left:0;
                     right:0;
                     bottom:0;
                     transition: all .5s ease-out;
                     }
     
    div.nav ul li a:hover:after{ width:100%;}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
       <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>About Me</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Resume</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

try with this.. just using :before instead of box-shadow

Answer (score 1):

Don't use box-shadow, but create an absolute positioned pseudo element with `:before`, which you can then animate

```css
div.nav {
  float:left;
}
div.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 180px;
}
div.nav ul li {
  border:1px solid #EAEAEA;
}
div.nav ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
  color: black;
  width:180px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:50px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 gold;*/
  cursor:pointer;
  position: relative;
}
div.nav ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: gold;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  
}
div.nav ul li a:hover:before {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-out;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
}
div.nav ul li a i {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
       <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>About Me</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Resume</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```